# Joomla 2.5 set default ACL permission values

Tags: permissions, acl, joomla2.5

I have developed a component and added ACL for viewing permissions in it and everything works great, the only issue is that when I install the component by default it uses 'inherited' permissions for view which somehow comes as denied and everytime I install the component I have to first change the permission to 'Allowed' so I wanted to ask if there is way to set default values for permissions like there is for everything else? If there is then what exactly is the syntax? Thanks

PS: Please don't provide me with [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_14#admin.2Faccess.xml) as I have read it and it doesn't solve my problem.

Following is my config.xml permissions code

```
<fieldset name="permissions" label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL" description="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_DESC">
        <field name="rules" type="rules" label="JCONFIG_PERMISSIONS_LABEL" filter="rules" component="com_name" section="component">
            <action name="core.view" title="View" description="View" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: I just browsed around in [Joomla Code Archive](http://api.joomla.org/li_Joomla-Platform.html) to find the code that reads the `config.xml`-file, but wasn't successful. Perhaps you can find something in the code...

Comment: I guess that won't help. Still can redirect me to the exact file/page?

Also usually the action line (in the middle of my code) is written in access.xml separately, I just put it in config to not write a file for a single line. You will fine it reading access.xml usually I guess.

Answer (score 1):

While installing the component you have to update the permission rules in `#__assets` table.

If we need to give full access to particular group like Manager or Author by default,

In `install.yourcomponent.php`, we have to write our own query like this `update #__assets` table.

In `#__assets` table there is `rules` field which it will be store all the permission value, so here we need to update the table using our value.

**For example:**

`update #__assets set`rules`='{"core.manage":{"6":1},"core.configuration":{"6":1,"7":1,"8":1},"core.admin":[],"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":{"8":1},"core.edit.state":{"8":1}}' where name ='com_yourcomponent' and title='yourcomponent title'`

Comment: Where is it defining the default values?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting your points correctly.Explain with some more details

Comment: I need to set default permission on installation like you can set default values of params.

Comment: Thanks. This might work but this clearly doesn't seem to be the standard way. Hasn't joomla provided any simple xml based configuration like the rest?